# differential equation $y' = \frac{-2x-y}{-5x+2y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[my attempt]
setting $u=\frac{y}{x}$
I got $\int\frac{(2u-5)du}{2(u-1)^2}=-\int\frac{dx}{x}$
what should be the next step ?

Answer (score 1):

write $$y'=\frac{-2+\frac{y}{x}}{-5+2\frac{y}{x}}$$ and with $$y=ux$$ we get
$$y'=u'x+u$$
$$u'x=\frac{2u^2+6u-2}{2u-5}$$ is separable

Comment: not -5x + y  the problem is -5x + 2y

Comment: @S.Ky he divide by $x$ denominator and numerator.

Comment: can you solve the equation now?